# How to create multiple variables dependent on a user number?

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7

I am currently attempting to make a simple Pig Latin generator that would allow sentences as well as single words. Basically I need to be able to create a certain amount of variables depending on how many words the user writes for me to be able to turn into Pig Latin.

I've already got my word splitter and it stores all the words into a variable, afterwhich I grab the first word with word1 = sentence_list[0].

**TL;DR**: How to create a certain amount of variables depending on how many words the user submits in a sentence?

Code so far:

```
print "Welcome to Pig Latin translator! Use this to translate to Pig Latin!"

def start():
    pyg = 'ay'

    original = raw_input("Type a word or sentence here to translate to Pig Latin: ")

    if len(original) > 0: #making sure user doesn't submit nothing
        print "Your word/sentence you want translated is " + original
        word = original.lower() #makes the word/sentence lowercase
        sentence_list = word.split(" ") #splits the sentence into multiple words
        print sentence_list
        lensentence = len(sentence_list) #gets how many different words there are
        word1 = sentence_list[0] #gets the first word in a sentence
        word1 = word + first + pyg #begins translating to pig latin
        word1 = new_word[1:len(new_word)] #finishes transslation by removing first     letter
    else:
        print "You didn't type anything!" #says if user didn't submit any characters

start()
```

Comment: Why create multiple variables when one dictionary or list would do? How'd you go about addressing all those variables later on?

Comment: Why don't you use a list?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that. I've only just started. Should I just finish the CodeCademy course before asking any more questions?

Comment: @Jjrage That sounds like a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this solves your problem. This uses a list comprehension so I suggest you finish the Codeacademy course to get a good grasp on them.  If you have any questions you can just ask.

```
print "Welcome to Pig Latin translator! Use this to translate to Pig Latin!"


def start():
    pyg = 'ay'

    original = raw_input("Type a word or sentence here to translate to Pig Latin: ")

    if len(original) > 0:
        print "Your word/sentence you want translated is " + original
        word = original.lower()
        sentence_list = word.split(" ")
        print sentence_list
        words = [w[1:] + w[0] + pyg for w in sentence_list]
        print " ".join(words)
    else:
        print "You didn't type anything!"

start()
```